# Using $.mobile.changePage and passing data

Tags: jquery, methods, jquery-mobile

I am trying to learn myself jQuery Mobile. I think it is really cool, but I am stuck at something. If I want to call this:

```
$j.mobile.changePage({ url: $j("#News"), data: "apple=banana", type: "GET"}, "slide", true, true);
```

It does not seem to work. I am not really known with passing data with jQuery, so mayby I am doing something wrong.

Kind regards, Senne

Edit: Sorry, put the wrong code up there...

Comment: I think it is a Bug. Because this does work -> url: "#News" <- but not properly (i get redirected to the same page)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know - url must be a real url *or* an id of another `div[data-role=page]`

To clarify:

Providing an ID shows up another div that is avaliable in the current document (You can create html files with multiple pages in them).

Also - jquerymobile is loading a page only once, and adding it to the document for later reference. No server side actions will be triggered later. (I'm not sure how it handles the calls with data provided)

Comment: to load the page you have to give it a URL. Where is the data supposed to be sent if you change page to one that is alredy in the current html document?

Comment: I'm noticing the same behavior; looking at Firebug or Fiddler, it makes the request to the specified URL (whether internal or external), executes all requests within that body, but doesn't display the actual page. I'm using the following: <a href="javascript:" onclick="$.mobile.changePage({url:'#21056140-5d67-434b-8b43-9de11d30a72f', data:'code=tbsurvey&apple=banana', type:'GET'}, 'slide', false, true);">link</a>

Answer (score 1):

Based on trial and error, this is what I see happening:

- **$.mobile.changePage**('#'+id, filter, false, true) refreshes the current view but doesn't execute the request on the server
- **$.mobile.changePage**({url:'#'+id, data:'code=apple=banana', type:'GET'}, 'slide', false, true) doesn't refresh the current view but does execute the request on the server
- **$.mobile.changePage**({url:'http://localhost/SomeOtherPage.aspx', data:'code=apple=banana', type:'GET'}, 'slide', false, true) refreshes the current view and executes the request on the server

So it seems that the base URL must be different to update the current view while executing on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a scenario where  I needed to capture a tap event on an item and display a loaded page (same html file) with details for the tapped item. The solution I found is semi-dependent on a few things, however:

- Your .js scheme should be contained within at least one "namespace", or property off of the global object, to prevent writing over anything important to the global object or being written over by external code.
- Your data must already be present in a .js object and or accessible by some other means.

Attaching a tap event to the element causing the page transition (or even ina  function causing a page transition problematically) allows you to create a function as follows:

```
function PageTransitionHandle(oEvent)
{
   // Set your stored data to a global object
   oYourNamespace.DataObject = oDataObject;

   // not necissary if already linked to other page but useful when attaching to
   // an image  or other element
   $.mobile.changePage("#otherPageId");
}
```

and  in the pageshow event for the next page:

```
function PageInit()
{
   var oPageData = oYourNamespace.DataObject;
   // Handle using data from here (i.e calling webmethod using parameters 
   // or setting data according to object)
}
```

Potentially this should work with external pages and internal pages since ajax loading methods are used, but I have not tested. This is useful for passing parameters or even whole data objects  to define other feilds, or letting a users information follow them, anything really.

Another route to look at is [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) but I haven't personally looked at this much yet